# How many eSIMs can an iphone XMAX hold?

Tags: esim

I have an iPhone XMAX and wonder, how many eSIMs can I store in it? How easy it is to switch between eSIMs? I would like to keep 10 different eSIMs and be able to easily switch between them (but don't need to use them simultaneously).

Comment: Do you mean iPhone XS max?

Comment: I think so, I thought its simply called X MAX

Comment: you can load 8 eSims

Comment: @Ruskes where can I look this up? Another answer says its just one.

Comment: 8 eSIMS?!?!  The link in your answer only references dual SIMS and of the iPhone doesn’t have a nano slot it can have dual eSIMS.  The XS DOES have a nano slot so just one then

Comment: @DougMasters it does say 8 or even more here https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212780 - so Im still confused. Is it 2? 8? More?

Comment: You can only use 2 at a time, not 8.  Ruskes answer says that applies to the iPhone 14 and your question is about the XS Max

Answer (score 2):

While the iPhone XS MAX supports dual SIMs, one is the nano-SIM, the other is an eSIM.  so, to answer your question, it supports one eSIM.

[iPhone XS MAX Technical Specifications](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP780?locale=en_US)

> **SIM Card**
>
> - Dual SIM (nano-SIM and eSIM)11
> - iPhone XS and iPhone XS Max are not compatible with existing micro‑SIM cards.

Comment: How easy is it to change esims?

Comment: It’s easy to change, but it’s got to be done by a carrier

Comment: This source says its 8 and more even: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212780 but not at the same time. However I don't need them to work at the same time, just be ready for switching.

Answer (score 1):

According to Apple you can have two SIM active at same time and switch between them.

Here are some of the many ways you can use Dual SIM:
Use one number for business and another number for personal calls.
Add a local data plan when you travel to another country or region.
Have separate voice and data plans.
Note: To use two different carriers, your iPhone must be unlocked.

Apple: iPhone 14 Supports Up to 8 eSIMs and Dual Active eSIMs
https://www.pcmag.com/news/apple-iphone-14-supports-up-to-8-esims-and-dual-active-esims

[Sim](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209044)

Comment: How is this answer different from the first one?

Comment: I found the source of the claim for 8 sims: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212780 how does this work? Obv. not at the same time but is it 8? Why do they say 8 and more?

Comment: You can have two active SMIS at same time, you can download 8 SIMS, but not active at same time (if you want to use any of those, you have to activate it fist, thus loosing one of the two (deactivating)